# Trying to set Data Validation requiring a "#" to be included in the input

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a data validation that will require a cell to have a "#" and will reject the input if it does not. I can't do it with normal data validation since people will have to be able to paste into the cell which will normally remove any validation I have set. I found out that if I write a script for the Data Validation on a set range, it will still run even if something is pasted into a cell. I've gotten far enough to flag cells that don't contain the "#" but can't figure out how to make it reject input that doesn't have it. This is where I am:

```js
function NoHasgtag() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("F7:F");
  var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireTextContains("#").build();

  range.setDataValidation(validation);
}
```

I was also thinking I could maybe get it to work with `.requireFormulaSatisfied()` and was trying this:

```js
function NoHasgtag() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("F7:F");
  var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",range,1)')');

  range.setDataValidation(validation);
}
```

and I'm getting the error:

> Missing ) after argument list. (line 3, file "Code")

I'm learning all this on the fly and I'm not really sure what I'm doing, so any help or explanations to where I'm going wrong would be super helpful! Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Hey @TravisMussells, was the answer I published useful to you? I'd love to know how you moved on with the issue you originally presented. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function NoHasgtag() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("F7:F");
  var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",range,1))')');

  range.setDataValidation(validation);
}
```

or:

```
function NoHasgtag() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("F7:F");
  var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('REGEXMATCH(range,"#")')');

  range.setDataValidation(validation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you have in your code is that:

```js
var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",range,1)')');
```

should be instead:

```js
var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",range,1))');
```

(notice the removed single quote)

Moreover, this code will not work because:

1. The formula is not valid.
2. Upon pasting values onto your sheet, the data validation will be removed.

#### Alternative

You can create an [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger that checks whether your `F7:F` range has been modified. If so, a new data validation is created.

Since what you are validating is quite simple, you don't really need a custom function validator. You can simply use the [`requireTextContains()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requiretextcontainstext) data validation method as follows:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;

  var lastRow = range.getRow() + range.getHeight() - 1;
  var firstCol = range.getColumn();
  var lastCol = firstCol + range.getWidth() - 1;

  if (range.getSheet().getName() == 'Sheet1' &&
      lastRow > 6 &&
      firstCol <= 6 &&
      lastCol >= 6) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("F7:F");
    var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireTextContains('#').build();

    range.setDataValidation(validation);
  }
}
```

You will only need to change `"Sheet1"` in the code so that it matches the Sheet name you want to operate upon.